# Prevent showing popup more than once. Ajax-add-result is already registered in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very dissapointed because I can't get rid of this issue! I have a product view and an "Add to Cart" button. If I click on the button, the form will be submitted (productAddToCartForm.submit(this)) and following function will be called:

```
var myAjaxify = function(button) {
button.prop('disabled', true);
if (this.validator.validate()) {
  $(this.form).request({
    onComplete: function(response) {
      var responseData = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
      if (responseData.success === 'true') {
        Dialog.confirm(
          responseData.message,
          {
            className: 'openit',
            width: 385,
            height: 220,
            destroyOnClose: true,
            id: 'ajax-add-result',
            closable: true,
            zIndex: 100,
            title: 'Added to Your Cart',
            okLabel: 'Continue Shopping',
            cancelLabel: 'Proceed to Cart',
            onCancel: function() {
              window.location = '/checkout/cart';
            },
            buttonClass: 'action-btn'
          }
        );
        ...
```

But it takes a few seconds till the popup shows up. And if I click on the "Add to Cart" button multiple times in the meanwhile, the popup appears more than once. If I don't close the popup fast enough I also get the error "ajax-add-result is already registered in the DOM". I tried to disable the button ($(this).prop('disabled', true);), but all my solutions break the script :(
Can anyone help me?

Every help is much appreciated.

Best, Hannes.

Comment: how are you executing myAjaxify?

Comment: Did you able to solve your problem? I am also facing same issue and till now I didn't got any fix for it. Please post your fix in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Unset the button :)

```
$( "#yourbutton").unbind( "click" );
```

After everything is loaded you can bind the event back.

Comment: And most people prefer  .off() rather than the unbind function now days. Its up to you what you want to use.